# Porcentaje en SQL agrupado por columna

Tags: porcentaje, sql

Tengo la siguiente estructura de tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De la cual quiere sacar el porcentaje del valor que viene en la columna prestamos agrupado por nro. de cuit.

He probado con esto pero en todos los casos me viene 100%

```
    SELECT
    cdd.NumeroIdentificacion ,
    cdd.Prestamos ,
    CAST(REPLACE(cdd.Prestamos,',','.') AS FLOAT) * 100 /( SELECT
                SUM(CAST(REPLACE(cdd.Prestamos,',','.') AS FLOAT))
          FROM
            CentralDeDeudores AS a
          WHERE
            a.NumeroIdentificacion = cdd.NumeroIdentificacion
            GROUP BY
            a.NumeroIdentificacion
        ) AS porcentaje 

FROM
    CentralDeDeudores cdd


GROUP BY
    cdd.NumeroIdentificacion,cdd.Prestamos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día teniendo en cuenta tu inquietud puedes mirar el siguiente ejemplo:

```
SELECT  T1.NumeroIdentificacion ,
        T1.Prestamos,
(SELECT COUNT(c.NumeroIdentificacion) 
    FROM CentralDeDeudores c
    WHERE c.NumeroIdentificacion = T1.NumeroIdentificacion
    GROUP BY c.NumeroIdentificacion ) AS Cantidad,
        ROUND((CAST(REPLACE(T1.Prestamos,',','.') AS FLOAT)/T2.TotalPrestamos),3) * 100 AS Porcentaje
        FROM CentralDeDeudores T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT  NumeroIdentificacion,
            SUM(CAST(REPLACE(Prestamos,',','.') AS FLOAT))  AS 'TotalPrestamos'
            FROM CentralDeDeudores
            GROUP BY
                NumeroIdentificacion
        ) T2
ON T2.NumeroIdentificacion = T1.NumeroIdentificacion
```

Es impotante tener en cuenta que el 100% es para cada cantidad si digamos hay 4 elementos el porcentaje va a dividirse en esos 4 ítems que tengan un identificador igual y así por cada cantidad que tengas en tus registros, te comparto una img. de como quedaría:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

La forma básica en `SQL` sería obtener en una consulta los totales de `Prestamos` por `NumeroIdentificacion` e integrarla luego en otra consulta con cada uno de los prestamos para llegar al porcentaje de los mismos. Algo así:

```
SELECT  T1.NumeroIdentificacion ,
        T1.Prestamos/T2.TotalPrestamos
        FROM CentralDeDeudores T1
    INNER JOIN (    SELECT  NumeroIdentificacion ,
                    SUM(Prestamos)  AS 'TotalPrestamos'
                    FROM CentralDeDeudores
                GROUP BY
                    NumeroIdentificacion
        ) T2
        ON T2.NumeroIdentificacion = T1.NumeroIdentificacion
```